# Windows 8: Different Themes or Different Wallpaper Slideshows for Multiple Monitors

Tags: windows-8, multiple-monitors, themes, desktop-customization, slideshow

I know I can assign different wallpaper for each monitor that is connected to my computer in Windows 8(by right clicking and selecting "set for monitor 1,2,etc"), but I don't know how to assign different wallpaper slideshow or different theme for each monitor. Can anyone tell me how to do that? It is quite interesting to see different wallpapers on different monitors, but seeing static wallpaper on each of those monitors is no fun. thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you set a theme or slideshow onto the desktop, it will set the same theme across all monitors, but when the images rotate, it will work its way through the monitors one at a time, changing each on the refresh interval.

For example if you have slideshow time set to every 10 seconds, it will change monitor 1, wait 10 seconds and change monitor 2, wait 10 seconds and change monitor 3, wait 10 seconds and change monitor 1.

AFAIK you cannot set multiple themes on each monitor, as theme selection does not have  "apply to monitor 2" option. This can only be set from within the wallpaper sub-theme setting.

Comment: OK. I think it will be fun if that "apply to monitor 2" option is usable for theme. thanks

Comment: yeah it would be kinda nice, but alas, no. I think one reason for it might be because there would be programming back flips to figure out how to handle it if a window spans two screens...